# Process hollowing - problem with getting the PEB address, apparently

Tags: c, winapi, process, ntdll

I am trying to implement basic process hollowing in a 32 bit process, in C.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winternl.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFOW si = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

    // Create the process to be hollowed
    BOOL processCreationSuccess =
        CreateProcessW
        (
            L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe",
            NULL,
            NULL, 
            NULL,
            FALSE,
            CREATE_SUSPENDED,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &si,
            &pi
        );
       
    if (!processCreationSuccess)
    {
        printf("Process creation failed with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("Process created at suspended state successfully\n");

    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
    UINT retLen = 0;
    NTSTATUS pebGotten = 
        NtQueryInformationProcess
        (
            pi.hProcess,
            ProcessBasicInformation,
            &pbi,
            sizeof(pbi),
            retLen
        );

    if (pebGotten != 0)
    {
        printf("Problem with getting PEB structure (NtQueryInformationProcess, %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("PEB is at address %p\n", pbi.PebBaseAddress);

    BYTE imageBase[0x8];
    UINT bytesRead = 0;

    BOOL readSuccess = ReadProcessMemory
    (
        pi.hProcess,
        pbi.PebBaseAddress + 0x10,
        &imageBase,
        0x8,
        &bytesRead
    );

    if (!readSuccess)
    {
        printf("Problem with getting PEB address, %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Image base address: %p\n", imageBase);

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)imageBase;
    if (dosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) {
        printf("Invalid DOS signature\n");
        return 1;
    }

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (ntHeaders->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {
        printf("Invalid NT signature\n");
        return 1;
    }

    PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER optionalHeader = &ntHeaders->OptionalHeader;
    if (optionalHeader->Magic != IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR_MAGIC) {
        printf("Invalid optional header magic\n");
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD entryPoint = optionalHeader->AddressOfEntryPoint;


    printf("Entry point: %p", entryPoint);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I create the process in suspended mode, and use NtQueryInformationProcess to get the pointer to the process's PEB. Then, i go to the peb's base address + 0x10 (i also tried 0x8 because im on 32 bit.
But every time, my program prints the "Invalid DOS signature" message, which i set up. This means that the image base is wrong. I also tried to debug it using IDA, and found out that pebBaseAddress points to somewhere weird...

I really don't know what to do, im struggling to find the issue.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: The PEB address isn't the same as the base address of the module used to create the process. Reinterpreting the contents of the PEB as if they were a mapped module is a meaningless operation. Anything from there is just going to be random, starting with the `e_magic` check (which, in itself, is fine; it's just not looking at data that is).

Comment: I see. But i still don't understand what's wrong - im passing the HANDLE of the newly created process to NtQueryInformationProcess. So it should return it's(notepad.exe's) PEB basic information, including the address of the PEB, shouldn't it?
Can you give me a clue on what should I change? Im quite new to this, so Im quite struggling to figure it out myself based on your comment.

Comment: You wrote "go to the peb's base address + 0x10" but nothing in this code actually does that

Comment: The issue is when you're reading the contents of the PEB into a variable called `imageBase`. To get the image base address you'd have to read the PEB's `Ldr` which is a pointer to a [`PEB_LDR_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb_ldr_data) structure, a linked list of modules, that expose the `DllBase` field.

Comment: I could do it with the peb's ldr yeah.. but isn't the imagebase in the PEB present at offset 0x10 (ox8 in 32 bit)? I mean, at least this is what this picture says:
https://2603957456-files.gitbook.io/~/files/v0/b/gitbook-legacy-files/o/assets%2F-LFEMnER3fywgFHoroYn%2F-LL65Cjy2bYGSydp-iUi%2F-LL6NaFQxL6gvvwjid7b%2Fpeb-overlay.png?alt=media&token=186ba355-ff58-450b-a92c-eb9f8faad2a9

Comment: What am i actually reading, when i read the offset 0x10 of the PEB? (which is the issue apperantly)

Comment: You've changed the code. Does the question need an update as well?

Comment: Hm, probably not. Now that you've (presumably successfully) acquired the image base address of the module used to create that other process, you're reading from that address in **your** process. Nothing reasonable will come of that. You will have to `ReadProcessMemory` again to see what's at `imageBase` in that other process.

Comment: I don't understand how I am reading from my process. I pass pbi.hProcess to `ReadProcessMemory`, which is a handle to that newly created process. So it should read the memory from that process.

Comment: `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)imageBase;` - That's constructing a pointer into **your** process' address space, which is subsequently dereferenced.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the sample: https://github.com/m0n0ph1/Process-Hollowing.

Comment: ^^What do I need to change, to get to the newly created process's address space then?                      and thank you Jeaninez, i'll take a look.

Comment: You'll need to `ReadProcessMemory`, as noted previously. A good book on overall system architecture in Windows would certainly help.

Comment: Yeah I see, but what should I pass to ReadProcessMemory ? What's the problem with what I'm doing now, and what should I actually change in my code to make the PEB part at least, work? I would be happy if you could shed some light on it.

Comment: Process memory is virtualized, where each process has access to the *entire* address space. When addresses cross process boundaries, you will have to record the process in which the address is meaningful. To read memory of a different process you have to call `ReadProcessMemory`. To get the image base into your process you have to call `ReadProcessMemory`, passing `imageBase` as the `lpBaseAddress` parameter, and provide a buffer local to your process to read into.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing tho? I still don't understand. Can you write the code I need to change so I can understand it? Cause it seems to me I'm doing everything right.

Comment: I tried to copy the code from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes
Just for the sake of creating the process But the handle, in pi.hProcess, in always a value of 0x000000EC or something close to that. Obviously this address is too small.
What am i missing or doing wrong? im stumped.

Comment: `imageBase` is a **pointer**. As such it's only meaningful within the process where it originated. To read the mapped module from that address you'll have to call `ReadProcessMemory`, passing `imageBase` as the address to read from.

Comment: You're absolutely right! That's what i've missed. Thanks!

Comment: Also keep in mind a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS runs in the WoW64 emulator. I believe there are two PEB's now (one for the 64-bit emulator, and one for the actual 32-bit application). You'll have to do some more research on what is required when interacting with a 32-bit process.

Comment: Yeah, I dug into that. The offset of the image base is at 0x8 instead of 0x10, as I said in the quedtion. Everything almost works now.